# Is it safe to call a synchronized method from another synchronized method?

Tags: java, thread-safety

If a synchronized method calls another synchronized method, is it thread safe?

```
void synchronized method1() {
     method2()
}

void synchronized method2() {
}
```

Comment: Would this article help answer, or where are you confused? http://kalyanchakravarthy.net/?p=413

Comment: Yes - you don't actually need to mark method2 as synchronized assuming its only called in the context given above.

Comment: Also, whether it is threadsafe will depend on what happens in the two methods. If they call non-threadsafe lists, for example, then they may not be threadsafe, if some other thread could modify that collection.

Comment: As an answer to what I would guess is the actual question: yes, the synchronized keyword uses recursive locks; you can safely call a synchronized method from another synchronized method.

Comment: It's been a while, but it's still the first hit on google, so: Yes, synchronized blocks/methods on the same object are reentrant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219376/reentrant-synchronization

Comment: See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/286374/49758

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yes, when you mark methods as `synchronized`, then you are really doing this:

```
void method1() {
    synchronized (this) {
        method2()
    }
}

void method2() {
    synchronized (this) {
    }
}
```

When the thread call gets into method2 from method1, then it will ensure that it holds the lock to `this`, which it already has, and thus it can pass through.

Now when another thread tries to get directly into method1 or method2, then it will block until it can get the lock (`this`), and only then it will enter into any of the two methods.

As noted by James Black in the comments, you do have to be aware with what you do inside of the method body.

```
private final List<T> data = new ArrayList<T>();

public synchronized void method1() {
    for (T item : data) {
        // ..
    }
}

public void method3() {
    data.clear();
}
```

Suddenly it's not thread safe because you are looking at a `ConcurrentModificationException` in your future because `method3` is unsynchronized, and thus could be called by Thread A while Thread B is working in `method1`.

Comment: I'm trying to answer a question almost identical to the one asked here. These are the 2 possible answers (the other 2 say it wont run), which is correct?

C. The code will run but there is a potential deadlock situation
D. The code will run fine as Java provides reentrant synchronization enabling a thread to acquire the same lock more than once ----- I'm guessing it's D, but maybe the potential deadlock situation is dependant on the method body?

Comment: @user3140993 The code here has no chance for a deadlock. `method3` shows unsafe threading operations, but you're spot on about the reentrant synchronization.

Answer (score 8):

> Is a method marked with synchronized call another synchronized method thread safe.

In general, it is not possible to say.  It depends on what the methods do, and what other methods on the same and other classes do.

However, we can be sure that calls to method1 and method2 on the same object made by different threads will not execute simultaneously.  Depending on what the methods do, this *may* be sufficient to say that the class is thread-safe with respect to these methods.

Answer (score 3):

From the Java Tutorials site http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

1. It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
2. when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads

So Java will ensure that if 2 threads are executing the same method, the methods will not executed consurrently but one after another.

But you need to be aware of the Liveness problem, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html

And also whether you are locking uncessarily, cause in the code you used **this**, which locks the whole object, if your object only needs sync access to one variable you should just lock that variable.

Comment: @Stephen Lee - you cannot lock a variable.  Then you say `synchronized (this.someVar)` you are looking on the object whose reference is held in `someVar`.  The distinction is very important.

Comment: An example of not locking on this. ```private final Object mSync; synchronized (this.mSync) {//some code}```